# Conditionally adding elements to an array while in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have this code for populating a list of comments to return:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
    $f_comments[] = array (
        'comment_id'    => $comment['comment_id'],
        'comment_body'  => $comment['comment_body'],
        'user_id'       => $comment['user_id'],
        'user_avatar'   => $comment['user_avatar'],
        'user_username' => $comment['user_username'],
        'timeago'       => formatter_common_format_time_string($comment['added']),
    );

    if (!empty($comment['user_picture']))
    {
        $f_comments[]['user_picture'] = $comment['user_picture'];
    }
}
```

The problem is, this is what gets returned:

```
"comments":[{"comment_id":9386,"comment_body":"Comment","user_id":46542,"user_avatar":"9","user_username":"TestUser","timeago":"about 2 hours ago"},{"user_picture":"ec237f517bc26b27d8e790c3a5d125841321552075"}]
```

...whereas I want user_picture in with the rest of the results, like this:

```
[{"comment_id":9386,"comment_body":"Comment","user_id":46542,"user_avatar":"9","user_username":"TestUser","timeago":"about 2 hours ago", "user_picture":"ec237f517bc26b27d8e790c3a5d125841321552075"}]
```

...however I can't see a way of doing this. I'm quite new to PHP so I'm probably missing something obvious. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the index your comment:

```
foreach ($comments as $i => $comment)
{
    $f_comments[$i] = array (
        'comment_id'    => $comment['comment_id'],
        'comment_body'  => $comment['comment_body'],
        'user_id'       => $comment['user_id'],
        'user_avatar'   => $comment['user_avatar'],
        'user_username' => $comment['user_username'],
        'timeago'       => formatter_common_format_time_string($comment['added']),
    );

    if (!empty($comment['user_picture']))
    {
        $f_comments[$i]['user_picture'] = $comment['user_picture'];
    }
}
```

Or just create a variable **$i = 0;** before the foreach an increase it before you close it **$i++;**